# 64bit COM client, 32bit COM server, typelibrary syskind

Tags: windows, com, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64-bit process that uses a 32bit (out-of-process) COM server.  It retrives typeinformation via IProvideClassInfo.  The typelibrary that it gets via GetContainingTypeLib has SYSKIND_WIN32 in its TLIBATTR.

Shouldn't COM marshal the type library to a SYSKIND_WIN64 lib?

Comment: Why should COM lie to you? In any case, why does this matter? Why is the value of this attribute important to you?

Comment: Well, my client code parses the typelib and creates some wrapper code from it dynamically.

Unfortunately, the typelib specifies wrong offsets and sizes for structure fields it contains (they are correct for 32-bit code, but not for 64-bit code), so the generated wrapper code is wrong.

In other words, the information in the type library doesn't match reality (as seen from the 64-bit code).

Comment: You mean your 64-bit client dynamically builds structures to pass as arguments to COM calls, but the TypeLib only gives you the definitions of the 32-bit version of these structures?

Comment: You are looking for magic that does not exist.  Structure layout is heavily dependent on compiler settings and bitness.  COM does *not* magically convert them, it has no idea what the compiler settings were.  Structures are always trouble in interop, you fix it by turning it into an interface instead where every field of the structure is a property of the interface.

Comment: Maybe if you can interpret the info returned by ITypeInfo::GetMops, you can create the same data structure that the marshaler expects...

Comment: Is there ANY documentation available about the data returned by ITypeInfo::GetMOPS?  I didn't find any...

Comment: @Hans: If you add your comment as answer then I can accept it.